# import configuration in spock integrationTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spock, spring-test

I'm having base test class like below:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = [Application])
class ApplicationTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext

    def "applicationContext check"() {
        expect:
        applicationContext
    }
}
```

here I'm trying to check all the beans loaded and app is started.

my configurations are there in like below structure.

```
demo-app(projectName/root) > config > application.yml
demo-app(projectName/root) > src > main > resources > application.yml
```

ApplicationTest class in below package

```
demo-app(projectName/root) > src > integrationTest > ApplicationTest.groovy
```

these config properties are not loading while running test.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide any real information about your project, I can just say two things:

1. Add the `spock-spring` dependency
2. Remove `@ContextConfiguration` as `@SpringBootTest` is recognized by `spock-spring`